# Solar charging for modern phones?

Tags: backpacking

Planning an extended backcountry backpacking trip and would like to use my iPhone as a camera, which means I need a way to charge it. I have a MagSafe battery pack that I could connect to a solar panel while hiking. Are there any recommendations for a lightweight, relatively inexpensive folding panel that could push enough juice to recharge the MagSafe pack? Specifically looking for something that can be placed on top of the pack to recharge the MagSafe battery while hiking.

I have previously used an all-in-one solar panel/battery combo (no name, sub-$50 cheapo Amazon solar power banks) for single site camping, but these are not workable for an extended trip changing campsites daily. The panel is really too small to do much more than top off the battery (if fully drained, solar panel does nothing!), it's difficult to position on a pack to get full sun while hiking, and these things are bricks - much heavier than I want to carry.

On a prior shorter trip, using Airplane + Low Power mode AND topping off halfway with a fully charged battery pack, I was able to make it one week - this trip is significantly longer (at least 12 days) and my phone is newer (larger screen = likely more battery drain).

Amazon is full of cheap options but I don't trust the reviews without some independent verification. REI has fancy options, but I'd prefer a panel that costs less than my backpack did! Several prior questions on this topic here but all are 6-8 years old.

Comment: “Several prior questions on this topic here but all are 6-8 years old.” Yeah, that’s why questions asking for specific recommendations are generally [off-topic](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) around here, but questions asking about features to look for are still on topic. Currently this question seems to be the former type.

Comment: On a 10-day rafting trip down the Grand Canyon a few small USB battery packs were enough to keep my wife's iPhone charged and taking pictures. I went with a point-and-shoot and a few extra batteries for it and had not issues.

Comment: @JonCuster But for backpacking the extra weight and volume of more battery packs is significant, whereas it isn't so much for rafting.

Comment: @bob1 - still less than the SLR with telephoto lens I used to take on multi week backpacking trips. No, minimizing weight is over stressed.

Comment: No time to write an answer now but consider how much power you can get out of a small panel, that's not well oriented. It's going to be slow but could be enough. Your battery pack needs to be optimised to make use of the variable output of the panel. There are manufacturers of battery packs designed to work with solar input; they sell panels too. I haven't tested any, but looked into them a year or two ago

Comment: @JonCuster Oh, I agree, having done the same with cameras myself. However, just because you can carry it, doesn't mean that you shouldn't look to optimize. Over a certain point weight definitely becomes a problem - carrying more than about 30% of your bodyweight is a serious risk for accidental falls and joint injury. If you are going 12 days with no resupply, you likely want to save every gram so that you can take extra food!